# Как написать скрипт отправки письма на php имея хостинг reg.ru?

Tags: php, email

Имеется рабочий скрипт и хостинг Reg.ru на которой есть почта inbox@test.ru, как переписать мой код, чтобы письмо приходило не просто под именем "inbox@test.ru", а чтобы оно исходило реально из этого адреса, очень жду ответа, заранее огромное спасибо!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2; URL=http://test.ru">
        <title>Форма обратной связи Test</title> 
    </head>
    
<body>

<?php 

// Почта, на которую приходит письмо
$sendto   = "test@gmail.com"; // почта, на которую приходит письмо

// Записываем данные из полей ввода в переменные
$username = $_POST['name'];
$usertel = $_POST['telephone'];
$usermail = $_POST['email'];

// Тема письма
$subject  = "Пришлите прайс";

// Дополнительные заголовки
$headers .= "From: Отправитель <inbox@test.ru>\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";

// Формирование тела письма
$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 2vw;'>";
$msg .= "<h1 style='font-weight: bold;'>Данные клиента:</h1>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Имя:</strong> ".$username."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Почта:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> ".$usertel."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";

// отправка сообщения
if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
  echo "<center><span style='color: green;'><h1>Сообщение успешно отправленно</h1><br><h2>Мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время! </h2></span></center>";
} else {
  echo "<center><img src='img/ne-otprevleno.png'></center>";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. Этот вопрос задавали не раз, ищите внимательнее. 2. `@` в коде использовать нельзя! Ошибки надо обрабатывать а не прятать!.

Comment: `чтобы оно исходило реально из этого адреса,` - что значит эта магическая фраза?

Comment: Когда я использую From то он просто вместо адреса отправителя подставляет то, что я написал и по этому Google почта например считает, что возможно такого адреса не существует и это спам, я пытаюсь именно эту проблему решить, как соединить почту хостинга с моим php скриптом, так, чтобы письмо исходило из встроенной почты моего хостинга

Comment: Юзайте Mailer. Хороший класс, много инфы. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer